# Contacts deleted when setting up e-mail on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, contacts, exchange-activesync

New iPhone 4S.  When I set up my e-mail exchange account all my contacts are deleted.  I have restored from back up twice and turned off the sync with contacts, calenders and reminders but it still deletes the lot.  Help?!  The prompts on the phone are insufficient to resolve.  Currently I can either have my contacts or my e-mail working but not both.

Comment: A suggestion. Put your contacts online. On your exchange account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have synced your iPhone with iTunes before, you can [restore from backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766).